# Solving for the inverse of a function in R

Tags: r, inverse

Is there any way for `R` to solve for the inverse of a given single variable function?  The motivation is for me to later tell `R` to use a vector of values as inputs of the inverse function so that it can spit out the inverse function values.

For instance, I have the function `y(x) = x^2`, the inverse is `y = sqrt(x)`.  Is there a way `R` can solve for the inverse function?

I looked up `uniroot()`, but I am not solving for the zero of a function.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

What kind of inverse are you finding? If you're looking for a symbolic inverse (e.g., a function y that is identically equal to sqrt(x)) you're going to have to use a symbolic system. Look at [ryacas](http://code.google.com/p/ryacas/) for an R library to connect with a computer algebra system that can likely compute inverses, Yacas.

Now, if you need only to compute point-wise inverses, you can define your function in terms of uniroot as you've written:

```
> inverse = function (f, lower = -100, upper = 100) {
   function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper)[1]
}

> square_inverse = inverse(function (x) x^2, 0.1, 100)

> square_inverse(4)
[1] 1.999976
```

For a given `y` and `f(x)`, this will compute `x` such that `f(x) = y`, also known as the inverse.

Comment: I was going to suggest generating a big vector `y <- f(seq(0,100,.001)` and using the results to build a distribution function of x in terms of y via `ecdf` or similar tools, but Mike's method is probably better.

Comment: Nice solution - makes good use of R functional programming genes. About the semicolons - I only use them when I want to write a multi-statement one-liner.

Comment: Why do R not give exact values like 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment as my reputation is too low.
I am a newbie to R, and it took me a while to understand Mike's code as I was not used to the way functions are defined in his answer.
Below is Mike's code in a longer, but (to me) easier readable notation:

```
inverse <- function(f, lower, upper){
  function(y){
    uniroot(function(x){f(x) - y}, lower = lower, upper = upper, tol=1e-3)[1]
  }
}
square_inverse <- inverse(function(x){x^2}, 0.1, 100)
square_inverse(4)
```

I hope it helps others newbies as well.

Comment: Why is it written as `function(f, lower, upper){  function(y){ ...}`

Comment: basically why is the `uniroot` function inside a function which is being returned? and where does the value y come from when calling `inverse`