# Parameter estimation of arbitrary function in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a *linear* but complex function in R, let's say

```
estimate.value <- function(x, y, z)
```

Now I have an output value and I want to estimate the input parameters one or two at a time. How do I do that?

e.g. I know that output value is 5 and and x=2, y=3 then how do I estimate **z**? or I know output value is 5 and only know x=2, how do I estimate **x and y**?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all: first you assume that your function is linear. So it writes simply f(x) = t(u) %*% x , where u and x are vectors (u is fixed) and t is the transpose operator ?

Comment: What do you mean "linear but complex"? Is it linear in the variables, e.g. `f = a*x+b*y+c*z`, or is it linear in the parameters, e.g. `f = a*exp(x)+b*cos(x)+c*log(x)`. Best to just show the function in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your question essentially relates to *inverting* a function. You could do this by employing root-finding. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10081571/2838134) for an answer on SO regarding this.