# Modify function input variable to achieve output of x.99

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data looks like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
    x_val = c(10.3, 14.3, 18.7)
)
```

After passing each `x_val` to `my_fun`...

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
    x * pi
}

df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(y_val = my_fun(x_val))
```

...I get the following:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
x_val    y_val
<dbl>    <dbl>
1  10.3 32.35840
2  14.3 44.92477
3  18.7 58.74778
```

How might I reverse the function (without just dividing by pi! because my actual function is a lot more complex) to find the appropriate value of `x_val` to get `y_val` that is the nearest `integer - 0.01` .. to achieve `x.99`:

```
32.99
44.99
58.99
```

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(y_val =  trunc(my_fun(x_val)) + 0.99)`

Comment: Alternatively you could add `ceiling(x) - .01` to your function.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear... I need to know the correct value of `x_val` to get 32.99 .... (10.501) .... without simply dividing by pi (because my actual function is a lot more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you have a function f(x_val) that is complex and you want the inverse function of f. You want to find x_val by knowing the y_val. By checking [Solving for the inverse of a function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081479/solving-for-the-inverse-of-a-function-in-r) you could try (adjust the lower and upper parts I do not know the limits of your function):

```
inverse = function (f, lower = -100, upper = 100) {
  function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper)[1]
}

yourfunction_inverse = inverse(my_fun, 0.1, 100)
```

And the results will be

```
results <- sapply(c(32.99, 44.99, 58.99), yourfunction_inverse)
```