# Construct an inverse regression via sapply and uniroot

Tags: r, inverse

I've a function as follows:

```
V <- seq(50, 350, by = 1)
> VK
    Voltage^0     Voltage^1     Voltage^2     Voltage^3 
-1.014021e+01  9.319875e-02 -2.738749e-04  2.923875e-07 
> plot(x = V, exp(exp(sapply(0:3, function(x) V^x) %*% VK)), type = "l"); grid()
```

Now I would like to do an inverse regression upon this certain function. I've seen [Solving for the inverse of a function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081479/solving-for-the-inverse-of-a-function-in-r) :

> inverse = function (f, lower = -100, upper = 100) {
>      function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mP23C.png)
>   }
>
> square_inverse = inverse(function (x) x^2, 0.1, 100)
>
> square_inverse(4)

and I'm trying to adjust it to my purposes as follows:

```
certain_function <- function(x=V) { exp(exp(sapply(0:3, function(x) V^x) %*% VK)) }

inverse = function (f, lower = 50, upper = 350) {
  function (y) uniroot((function (x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper)[1]
}

inverse_regression = inverse(certain_function, 50, 350)

inverse_regression(2)
```

Unfortunately this yields:

```
 Error in uniroot((function(x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

As far as I understood: The error means that there are more roots than only one (uniroot can only handle one root) but there shouldn't be more than one root since it's a strictly monotonically increasing function.
The warnings I do not understand..

edit: I'm trying to get behind it.. I removed both exponentials which yields the following plot:

[image]

and this still generates the following error:

```
> inverse_regression(0.1)

 Error in uniroot((function(x) f(x) - y), lower = lower, upper = upper) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.na(f.lower)) stop("f.lower = f(lower) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.na(f.upper)) stop("f.upper = f(upper) is NA") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Why is this? Obviously the curve has opposite signs at both end points..  I guess end points mean the points left and right to the root?

Comment: Ok, I solved it. Don't know what it was exactly but when I transformed the matrix-vector product to a regular function it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the inverse regression did not work due to the definition of "certain_function". This is a matrix-vector product and the result is a vector again. Therefore I transformed this to a regular function `function(x) exp(exp(sum(x^0*VK[1],x^1*VK[2],x^2*VK[3],x^3*VK[4]))` and now it is working.
Hence, one should be aware of the bounds each time in general.