# R - Inverse cumulative distribution method with given function

Tags: r, inverse, cdf, kolmogorov-smirnov

I have a given function (let's call it f(x)) and I used the Monte Carlo method to normalized it. I calculated  the probability density function and I got the cumulative distribution function from integrating that.

```
f = function(x) ...

plot(f,xlim = c(0, 5), ylim = c(0, 1),main="f(x)")

mc.integral = function(f, n.iter = 1000, interval){
  x = runif(n.iter, interval[1], interval[2])
  y = f(x)
  mean(y)*(interval[2] - interval[1])
}

MC = mc.integral(f, interval = c(0, 8))
print(MC)

densityFunction <- function(x){
  return ((f(x)/MC)) 
}

distributionFunction <- function(x){
  return  (integrate(densityFunction,0,x)$value)
}

vd <- Vectorize(distributionFunction)
plot(vd,xlim = c(0, 8), ylim = c(0, 1),ylab = "y",main="E(f(x))")
```

Now my next task is to use the inverse transform method / inverse cumulative distribution method to generate samples and test it with the Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test, but I don't know how should I do in R.

Can you please give me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/184325/how-does-the-inverse-transform-method-work) shows us how to generate a sample using the inverse transform method:

```
sample <- vd(runif(1000))

> head(sample)
[1] 0.28737403 0.59295499 0.30814305 0.27998306 0.07601228 0.52753327
```

Therefore, generating 10 different random samples could be done with:

```
sample <- list()
for(i in 1:10){
  set.seed(i)
  sample[[i]] <- vd(runif(1000))
}
```

Afterwards, loop `ks.test` over the list:

```
lapply(sample, function(x) ks.test(x, pnorm))
```

will give you the output of a test vs. normality for each sample. Choose the size of your samples wisely, as most tests for normality are prone to be significant for large samples even with small differences (reference [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)).

Comment: Thank you, I think I can solve with that. However, I think I should use the inverse cumulative distribution method, because the regular one does not need the CDF or PDF. In this case what are the modification in your steps?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081479/solving-for-the-inverse-of-a-function-in-r) for an explanation of how to inverse a function in R. I hope you can solve it with that.

Comment: Thank you very much