# Rewriting Equation in terms of another variable in R

Tags: r

I have a function, such as `Q = 4000-50P`, written in `R` as 
`q1 <- function(p_)pmax(0,4000-50*p_)`

and I want to rewrite the equation in terms of `P`, to get `P = 80-(1/50)*Q`, written in `R` as `p1 <- function(q1_)pmax(0,80-(1/50)*q1_)`

Is there a way for `R` to solve a function/equation for another variable? I want to tell `R` to solve the first equation in terms of `p_`. I can't seem to find any answers online. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for manipulation of the formula of the function or for a numeric solution?

Comment: If you want a numeric solution, the question is duplicated, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081479/solving-for-the-inverse-of-a-function-in-r).

Comment: I'm looking for a manipulation of the formula of the function, not a numeric solution

Comment: Thanks Juan! The link works perfectly

Comment: Eventually you can use the package `formula.tools` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formula.tools/formula.tools.pdf There is a function `invert()`